# Avoid the subtitle left alone at the end of a page

Tags: css, epub

By increasing or decreasing the lettering style in epub, sometimes the subtitles are left alone at the end of the page.

How could I avoid this?

I wish that this subtitle are not left alone at the end of a page, and have a minimum of 2 lines of the next paragraph. Otherwise it should start on a new page.

I try to use a div containing the subtitles and the first paragraph, but now I get a big blank space on the page preceding the subtitle.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this using CSS properties like page-break-after and page-break-before...
For example on title class I add "page-break-after: avoid;" so that it sticks with following sub-title (I also add the same on chapter title so that it is not separated from chapter first paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using page-break-after, page-break-before, and page-break-inside is that they are block elements, which means you have to use them within a span or div. If you just apply them to a normal style, they are ignored (even if you add !important to the property).

Here's what we do:

**CSS:**

```
div.headbreaks {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="headbreaks">
<h1>Some Awesome Heading Goes Here</h1>

<p>
Bacon ipsum dolor amet filet mignon tempor doner rump bacon, 
ex tenderloin salami consequat jerky pig meatball frankfurter.
Porchetta beef dolore aliquip pig, bacon excepteur. Cow dolore
shankle prosciutto fatback. Elit ut frankfurter aliqua pork loin
aliquip, shank strip steak cow incididunt fugiat in irure jerky
turducken.
</p>
</div>
```

This ensures that the items contained within that div will stay together. If a page break is needed, the reader should force these items to the top of the next page.

HTH